# How to change background of combobox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.6.1

The problem with the combobox is that i cannot change the background of the 'combobo'. the foreground and background color of the combobox items do change tough.

I tried many things with xaml code. also in the designer it says background yellow but its still standard gray.

screenshot from designer: https://ibb.co/t8gtGw4

```
    <ComboBox Foreground="#FFFFFF" Background="#FF7A7A00" x:Name="cBox_nosave" Width="149.8192" Height="22" Canvas.Left="23.7296000000033" Canvas.Top="40.7904000000016">

        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ComboBox>
```

What i want to achieve is that the combobox is like dark mode still. so background should be black or transparent and text should be with. As i said the items are fine tough but the combobox itself.

Comment: yes but that does not help for me. I came across that post before i used some code to fix issues of mine. the colored comboboxitems for example they have changed.

Comment: You need to override the appropriate template. You can use the default styles for the `ComboBox` provided by Microsoft: [ComboBox Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates#combobox-controltemplate-example). Just modify the required parts to meet your expectations. You can also extract the template by right clicking on the `ComboBox` in the XAML designer and selecting _Edit Template/Edit a Copy_.